# Sync collection changes with the backend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I use Backbone.js and I have a collections of models. This collection is retrieved and displayed on the front-end. On the front-end, I want the user to remove and add new models to the collection.

When the user is finished and he clicked "save", I want the entire collection to be updated. Meaning that when clicking 'save', the collection is synced (somehow). Added models are saved and removed models are deleted.

If I manipulate the collection by removing and adding models, and then use ex:

```
this.collection.sync()
```

Will it remove and add models?

Comment: the question is: do you want the full collection to be send in each save?

Comment: There is a tradeoff between number of `client server calls` vs `size of call` vs `number of db operations`. But if you dont care about all of thses, you  can create some function at the server side that deletes every record not in the incoming list and add the list to it.  Then you can do `this.collection.sync('update',this.collection)`

Comment: @oak There is only one save-call. So I would only send in the collection once.
Best thing to do everything in one request.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to achieve this.

## Make an API endpoint to manage the models

When adding/updating a model, save the model directly with [`.save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) and when a model is removed, call [`.destroy`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) on it.

The collection also has a [`.create` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) which adds the new model to it and saves it at the same time.

> Best thing to do everything in one request.

Not always. The collection could be big and the changes rather small, so exchanging 100 objects with the server each time instead of X small requests to add, delete or update a model within the list.

**Pros**

- **Reusable endpoints** to manage individual models
- **Light data transfer**, faster than sending the whole collection (only changes are sent through partial updates)
- Possible **custom behaviour** for each action
- Easy **real-time update** implementation

**Cons**

- More requests when doing a lot of changes
- Needs models to have ids
- Additional endpoints to manage
- Not meant for bulk operations (save all models at once)

## Put the collection's `models` array into a model

Collections are not meant to be saved. Instead, put the `models` of the collection into a model which communicates with an API endpoint. This endpoint should expect an object with an array field, which can serve to replace the collection server-side.

```
var CollectionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "collection/endpoint/"
});

var myModel = new CollectionModel();

// ...sometime later...

myModel.save({
    arrayAttribute: yourCollection.toJSON()
}, { patch: true });
```

**Pros**

- **One endpoint**; always the same call to the API
- **Easy to implement**; just in one place where the save occurs

**Cons**

- All models are transferred on every request regardless of changes
- Could be slow if the collection is big

---

[Collection's `.sync` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L796-L799) is only a proxy to [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) and do nothing without the correct parameters. It is only used internally within `.fetch` ([line 1055](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1055)) and isn't meant to be used directly, unless adding a custom behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it! But there is no way to send one model at the time for every change. The collection can only be updated at the end, when the user click "save".

Comment: @tork that's what the second part of my answer is all about